# Angular 2 RC5 <base href="..."> breaks routing

Tags: javascript, html, svg, angular

I've stumbled upon a problem related to `<base href="...">` problem. It seems that Angular 2 heavily relies upon this tag. However the tag itself impacts `<svg>...</svg>` declarations in a way that is not suitable for my case ([there's a lot properly described info on this issue on the internet](https://github.com/meanjs/mean/issues/1224)). But when I remove my `<base href="...">` the application instantly breaks.

After lurking for a solution for few days I've found the way to make my application work at least somehow without `<base href="...">`

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    routing
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeroesComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    HeroDetailComponent
  ],
  providers: [
    HeroService, {
      provide: APP_BASE_HREF, // <------------ this guy here saves the day
      useValue: '/'
    }
  ],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

However without `<base href="...">` the application has became less stable in relation to routing. Basically it breaks and throws exception "maximum stack size reached" when I'm trying to reload page from a route other than default.

I was unable to reproduce the problem with plunkr however also I was unable to make [standard angular tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt5.html) work without `<base href="...">`

Here are the links to

[Original plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/8k2reiFIGqPLKsPuDR6l?p=preview)

[Modified plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/faa6IlZ1SLcOJwP0PAca?p=preview)

If you'll open modified one's console you will see an error.

There is absolutely no information on this issue on the internet, I was never dealing with `<base href="...">` and I'm new to angular 2. So what would the best starting point would be towards investigation of this problem?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you ever solve or report this?

Comment: I didn't report it, neither I have tested it with official Angular 2 Release

Answer (score 1):

You can provide

```
{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' }
```

for the router to override `<base href="...">` while SVG keeps depending only on the `<base href="...">`.

See also https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8939

Comment: What I was trying to say is that I've used your solution however it breaks angular 2 routing...

Comment: Sorry, I missed that you had that already. If that doesn't work I think it's worth a bug report (with a Plunker to reproduce).

Comment: Thanks no problem, I have real problem with identifying the source of an issue and reproducing it in plunkr though...

Comment: I've spent nearly all day trying to figure out what happens, no luck...

Comment: Plunker is a bit different because it requires the current path for `<base href="...">` or `APP_BASE_HREF`. If you can reproduce in a new project locally that contains the same code as the Plunker, then this should be enought as a repo case I guess.